# Does NASA use any of the twilight designations?

Tags: nasa, terminology

Do the differences in [civilian, nautical, and astronomical twilight](https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/different-types-twilight.html) have any technical relevance to NASA either on Earth or any other object in the solar system where a probe has landed?  Does NASA have an official designation when night begins?

**Civil twilight** occurs when the Sun is less than 6 degrees below the horizon.

**Nautical twilight** occurs when the geometrical center of the Sun is between 6 degrees and 12 degrees below the horizon.

**Astronomical twilight** occurs when the Sun is between 12 degrees and 18 degrees below the horizon.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty niche, but I remember the terms coming up in a discussion about when the shuttle simulator visual scenes for the prelaunch/landed vehicle should switch to "day" graphics. (The sim was switching at sunrise and some felt it should do so at civil dawn) I doubt I have any documentation on this but I'll take a quick riffle.